# How to make latex macros use special characters

Tags: macros, tcolorbox

I have made next macros for code highlighting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xspace}

\definecolor{CodeBg}{RGB}{238, 241, 242}
\definecolor{CodeText}{RGB}{88, 97, 107}
\newcommand{\code}[1]
{\tcbox
    [on line, 
    boxsep=4pt, 
    left=-0.5mm,
    right=-0.9mm,
    top=-0.4mm,
    bottom=-0.4mm,
    colframe=white,
    colback=CodeBg,  
    %   highlight math style={enhanced}
    ]{\normalfont\ttfamily\color{CodeText} #1}\xspace
}

\begin{document}
    There is a function \code{strcmp(str1, str2)} that compares two strings. Varriable of \code{int} type is returned by \code{strcmp(str1, str2)}.
\end{document}
```

It works exactly as I want to but there is a problem: code often contains special characters (`#_%&*`) and pasting some code and fixing all of them by placing `\` before each sounds not good.

Is there a way to make `\code{}` macros to consume entire argument as plain text?

Comment: See `\DeclareTotalTCBox` example using `/tcb/verbatim` in section 4.20 of the [`tcolorbox` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) and description of `\DeclareTotalTCBox` in section 3.3.

Comment: @cabohah I read for a bit and decided to use minted package with tcolorbox. Thank You!